# Can I use VBA in MS Access to add a control to a tab control (TabCtl) object?

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

I want to use VBA in MS Access to dynamically add a subform control to a tab control object on a form. Basically, I have a 99% working solution where users need to generate a custom form. They can select the type and number of drop-downs they want, and it will generate a main form and paste in a subform with all of those controls. If there are too many controls (22" form limit in Access), it splits them into multiple subforms -- hence the tab control. The only thing I can't get it to do is paste the new subforms into the tab control itself.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. In my research I did find VBA methods to add controls to TabStrips and TabPages, but those aren't relevant to MS Access. The TabCtl object itself doesn't seem to have any properties related to adding controls within it (yet this is something you can obviously do in the GUI).

```
Sub AddControlToTabControl()

    Dim frm As Form
    Dim subForm As Form
    Dim tabCtl As tabControl
    
    Set frm = Forms!Form1
    Set subForm = Forms!Form1_subForm
    Set tabCtl = frm!tabCtl
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name
    
    'Here are some things that aren't valid
    tabCtl.Pages(0).Add (subForm)        'Pages collection does not have an Add property
    tabCtl.Controls.Add (subForm)        'Controls collection does not have an Add property
    tabCtl.Add (subForm)                 'tabCtl object does not have an Add property

End Sub
```

I reviewed the [Tab Control object Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.TabControl), including all of the properties I thought would make sense, but there doesn't seem to be anything on how to put a control specifically on the tab control itself.

I also used VBA to paste the subform onto the main form using coordinates that would be on top of the tab control, but it just created overlapping objects.

Comment: It may be simpler to hide/unhide the subform and a collection of controls and adjust the properties of these.

Comment: @Gustav, good point, but since the subforms are being created dynamically, I don't know how many there will be. There might be 1, there might be 5. There's also a 255-control limit to Access forms that I'd imagine I'd run into if I were pasting in many subforms like that.

Comment: Well, then set a maximum of five subforms/tabs and hide the four until needed.

Comment: I confirmed it's actually a limit of 754 controls over the life of the form (so deleting and re-adding doesn't reset that number), but that should be good for practical purposes. I like your approach and will add buttons to display each subform one at a time. Thanks @Gustav!